# Async Controller Action Method invoke by using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I am new to AngularJS, I want to know how to call an Async Controller Action Method in MVC by angularJS. I already tried with below code. Can someone help me in this. Here is my AngularJS code

```
 $scope.updateEmp = function () {
        var response = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "/Home/UpdateCustomer",
            data: JSON.stringify($scope.Customer),
            dataType: "json"
        }).success(function () {
            $scope.cancel();
            toaster.pop('success', "Success", 'Updates Successfully...!!');
           // showAlert("alert-success", "Updated!");

        }).error(function () {
            toaster.pop('error', "Error", 'Error while getting data', null, 'trustedHtml');
           // alert("Error while getting data");
        });
        // return response;
    }
```

My Action Method is below

```
  [HttpPost]
    public async void UpdateCustomer(Customer Upcustomer )
    {
        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (BusinessEntities dbContext = new BusinessEntities())
                {

                    var customer = dbContext.Customers1.First(c => c.CustomerID == Upcustomer.CustomerID);

                    customer.Fname = Upcustomer.Fname;
                    customer.Lname = Upcustomer.Lname;
                    customer.Age = Upcustomer.Age;
                    customer.Adderss = Upcustomer.Adderss;
                    customer.ContactNo = Upcustomer.ContactNo;

                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                    // return EmptyResult;
                    // return Json(customers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    //return View(customers);
                }
            });

    }
```

Comment: Can post the method that you want to call and what is the purpose? Be more clear.

Comment: If you are talking about an ASP.NET MVC async action method, the fact that it is async on the server side is irrelevant to how it is called by HTTP clients.

Comment: I edited my question, please have a look

Comment: Have you checked on the MVC website? More specifically their WebAPI section?

Comment: There's a tutorial on AngularJS + ASP.NET MVC [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/3-644)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know where your controller method is declared but i suggest it should look like this:

```
$scope.getAllCustomers = function(){...}
```

and then in the callback function:

```
}).success(function () {
    $scope.getAllCustomers();
```

If this is not what you meant, please specify the problem more clearly ^^

Comment: Thanks Micromonger for your response, now i edited my question...please have a look.

Comment: Sorry, but i've no idea of c# dude :D
The only thing I found that might be of your interest is the following =/
http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/